# Change date format in Kusto

Tags: kql

I have the following date `2022-08-21` in the DateCol of a table and I would like to format this as `August 2022`. I tried the following `format_datetime(DateCol, 'MMMM yyyy')` but that return `0808 2022`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The format specifiers in the question are working as expected:

MM formats the month, from 01 through 12. You have MMMM so two times MM thats why 0808.

yyyy formats the year as a four-digit number. Thats why 2022.

Month is only supported as a numeric value so you can use something like:

```
let months = dynamic({"1":"January", "2":"February", "3":"March","4":"April","5":"May","6":"June","7":"July","8":"August","9":"September","10":"October","11":"November","12":"December"});
let fullDate = datetime(2022-08-21); 
print strcat(months[tostring(getmonth(fullDate))], " ", getyear(fullDate))
```

Check usage of [datetime_part()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/datetime-partfunction), [monthofyear()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/monthofyearfunction),[getyear()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/getyearfunction) for further information